# Mathematics behind distance estimation using camera

Tags: trigonometry

Can some one explain the logic and calculations in deriving the distance/depth(**z**) value in the attached research paper. Kindly make your explanation elaborate for me to understand clearly as i was not good in mathematics from school days.[image]

Comment: What is the research paper that this picture came from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your finger straight up, away from your face, directly in front of your nose.  Close one eye.  Open it.  Close the other eye and open it.  Your finger moved quite a bit.  Now look at something a few meters away and try the same exercise.  Not as much movement.  This "movement" between one eye and the other (or one camera and another) is called disparity.  By trigonometry (as in the figure you posted) disparity is inversely proportional to distance.  Using the equations you posted, and drawing triangles, you can derive the relationship.  If $x_L$ is the "position in a coordinate system of the left camera" and $x_R$ is the "position of a coordinate system of the right camera", then disparity $\delta = x_L - x_R$.  (Different authors use different conventions, sometimes this equation appears with a minus sign).

[image]

By similar triangles, we can write the equations for $x_L$ and $x_R$:

$\displaystyle \large \frac{x_L}{f} = \frac{X+\frac{b}{2}}{Z}, \quad  \frac{x_R}{f} = \frac{X-\frac{b}{2}}{Z}$

so that the disparity is:

$\large \delta = x_L -x_R = \frac{b f}{Z}$.

Here, $b$ is the baseline distance between two pinhole cameras and $f$ is the shared focal length of each camera.  We see that disparity is inversely proportional to $Z$, the vertical distance from the point we are observing, and the horizontal line through the origin, $O$.

Comment: Thanks a lot mjw.  It really helped in understanding what disparity is.  I would also like to understand the relationship between the triangles and the math calculations behind deriving the distance.

Comment: I've redrawn the figure so that I could write the equations "in my own words".  Hope this is helpful and understandable.

Comment: Notice that the disparity $\delta$ is independent of $X$ and only depends on $Z$ (along with the constants $b$ and $f$).

Comment: Thanks a lot mjw. I am can understand the calculations easily now.

Comment: @Code_Kid,  You're welcome!