# Geometry: Showing that depth is proportional to disparity for depth images

Tags: geometry

In the following image we have two lenses with the same focal length with openings at $O$ and $O'$, with known distance between them $B$ (either two separate cameras or a depth camera, although this is may be very different than how depth cameras really operate). The points $p_u$ and $p'_u$ are the intersection of a point in $3$-D space $P$'s ray intersecting intersecting a line at a $z$-distance equal to the focal length from $O$ and $O'$ respectively (which I guess by the diagram is 1, but we could scale this for different data). $B, f,$ and $z$ are known as in the camera calibration parameters and a final depth image. Ultimately I'm looking for a mapping between a depth image to a disparity image.

The diagram then states that the disparity scalar $p_u - p'_u$ is inversely proportional to depth but I am not sure why this is the case. Insights appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remark: you are in the domain of **epipolar geometry**, an old subject that has been completely renewed since 30 years. "epipolar" is an essential keyword for further research on these issues.

You will find an answer [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3162573), based on similar triangles.

See the nice presentation [here](https://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs143/2009/lecture27.pdf).

Remark: I have found the first reference using the remarkable research tool: https://approach0.xyz/ (able to locate meaningful correspondences between formulas) targetting MSE (Math Stack Exchange) and AOPS (Art Of Problem Solving).

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed.